# Addressing Abu Bakr's RA statement

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, authenticity

> "Although he had such a faith, which was too great to suffice all the inhabitants of the earth, he was afraid that his heart might go astray. So, he used to utter, while weeping: ?Would that I have been a bitten tree!' Whenever he was reminded of his position in Allah's sight, he would say: ?By Allah! I would not rest assured and feel safe from **THE DECEPTION OF ALLAH** (la amanu limakr Allah), even if I had one foot in paradise.'" (Khalid Muhammad Khalid, Successors of the Messenger, translated by Muhammad Mahdi al-Sharif [Dar al-Kotob al-Ilmiyah, Beirut Lebanon, 2005], Book One: Abu Bakr Has Come, p. 99; bold and capital emphasis mine)

Can someone determine the authenticity of this statement? I found it in an anti-islamic website. If by chance that it is authentic, what is the correct translation and how can it be interpreted?

Comment: Seems to be paraphrased to propagate their view, the original can be seen [here](https://books.google.com.pk/books?id=9_xsDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA21&ots=_Y89OdMc6S&dq=Khalid%20Muhammad%20Khalid%2C%20Successors%20of%20the%20Messenger%2C&pg=PA99#v=onepage&q&f=false). The verse [7:99](https://quran.com/7/99) is also relevant.